# Python Response Datatype - How to access data

Tags: python, python-2.7, data-structures

I am working on a python program that connects to a database, and returns an entry. I got the following response, but I am unable to extract the variable for "Geofence" from the result.

I can get "Items" by doing `response["Items"]`, but I cant figure out how to get down to "Geofence", as in :`"S": "Geofence"`

```
{
  "Count": 1,
  "Items": [
    {
      "Lat": {
        "N": "34.065"
      },
      "Serial": {
        "S": "0001"
      },
      "Lon": {
        "N": "32.875"
      },
      "Geofence": {
        "S": "Geofence"
      },
      "Time": {
        "S": "20170221T010628Z"
      }
    }
  ],
  "LastEvaluatedKey": {
    "Serial": {
      "S": "0001"
    },
    "Time": {
      "S": "20170221T010628Z"
    }
  },
  "ScannedCount": 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `response["Items"]` is a list, you need the relevant index (in this case it's 0) and than navigate to the key `"Geofence"` and `"S"`

```
print (response["Items"][0]["Geofence"]["S"])
```

Will output the result:

```
"Geofence"
```

If you have more than one item in the list you could loop them:

```
res = []
for item in di["Items"]:
  res.append(item["Geofence"]["S"])

print (res)

>>> ['Geofence']
```